# R function dbGetQuery returns 1x1 table with name from function dbConnect

Tags: r

I have following problem in R.

I connected to database using RPostgres package function dbConnect:

**dbConnect(m, dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=example, password=password)**

The name of user is 'example'
The name of one of the tables in database is also 'example'.

While running: **dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * from example")** instead of getting the table,
I get data frame 1x1 with only one value : example (the same as user value in dbConnect function)

It seems like the command **dbGetQuery(db, "SELECT * from example")** returns value of user from
**dbConnect(m, dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=example, password=password)** 
instead of returning table from database.

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you passed the connection object to the get command? So, `conn <- dbConnect(m, dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=example, password=password)` and then `dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * from example")`.

Comment: Yes I did, so that's not the reason :(

Comment: Is it to do with schemas? What happens if you do `select * from schema.example`?

Comment: And does the problem only happen with the table called `example` or does it happen with all tables?

Comment: Only or this one, and this solution `select * from schema.example` that you wrote works, thank you :)

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Will you accept the answer I posted below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding my previous comment as an answer:
It looks like `dbGetQuery()`  was getting confused between the username and the table name. Adding the schema name to the query works.

```
conn <- dbConnect(m, dbname=dbname, host=host, port=port, user=example, password=password)
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT * from schema.example")
```